# Varnish - generating http header overflows

Tags: header, overflow, varnish

I've installed a monitoring template in Zabbix for Varnish (it's 6.0 LTS), and now I'm getting high level warnings that say:

Varnish Cache[] - MAIN.losthdr (HTTP header overflows / sec) (.....:varnish.stat["","MAIN.losthdr"]): 0.07 eps

I've been trying to look up the Varnish docs and google around what exactly is a "header overflow" in their case but very little I found about it, including more deatiled explanation about what is MAIN.losthdr.
Of course, I could just supress the alert, but I'm eager to dig into the cause further

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `MAIN.losthdr` counter keeps track of the number of times we *lost*  a header, meaning there was a *header overflow*.

## Reasons why this could happen

There are various reasons why this could happen:

- You might have run out of *workspace*
- You might have reached [`http_max_hdr`](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.0/reference/varnishd.html#http-max-hdr)
- You might have reached [`http_req_hdr_len`](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.0/reference/varnishd.html#http-req-hdr-len)
- You might have reached [`http_resp_hdr_len`](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/6.0/reference/varnishd.html#http-resp-hdr-len)

## How to inspect

You can monitor your workspace counters using the following `varnishstat`command:

```
varnishstat -1 -f "MAIN.ws_*"
```

You can also check the current values for each of the header limits. Here's how to do this:

```
varnishadm param.show http_max_hdr
varnishadm param.show http_req_hdr_len
varnishadm param.show http_resp_hdr_len
```

You can also use `varnishlog` to look into your traffic in real time and filter out requests that have header issues. Here's how you can do this:

```
varnishlog -g request -q "BogoHeader"
```

## How to fix

If it's a workspace issue, you might want to tune your workspace settings.

If it turns out you have too many headers or they are too long, the `varnishstat` or `varnishlog` commands will help you identify what's going on. Either the values will be too low, or the headers that are received by the client or returned by the origin are unreasonably big.

Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, that's it. It was about workspace_client. Thanks for the quick info